# "set-window-option -g mode-keys vi" doesn't work in .tmux.conf

Tags: vim, tmux

I've been able to turn-on the vi-mode inside tmux successfully by pressing `C-a :` (I've changed default prefix) and then typing `set-window-option mode-keys vi`. However, I can't make it stick by adding into `~/.tmux.conf`. Here is my config:

```
# Change default prefix key to C-a
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix 'C-a'
bind-key 'C-a' send-prefix

# Configure Vim mode for navigating text and selection
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection

# Allow navigating panes with vi-like commands.
bind k selectp -U
bind j selectp -D
bind h selectp -L
bind l selectp -R
```

Notably, navigating panes using `kjhl` keys also doesn't work. Perhaps this is because tmux fails to execute set-window-option earlier in the script. What's wrong here?

Comment: What is your tmux version?

Comment: `tmux -V` returns `tmux 1.8`

Comment: Hm have you tried using alias `setw -g mode-keys vi`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Please post that as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `setw -g mode-keys vi`

Comment: Works in `tmux-2.7`

Comment: this is not working fo rme using tmux 3.0a

Answer (score 10):

`"set-window-option -g mode-keys vi"` works in tmux 2.1 and above.

`"setw -g mode-keys vi"` works in tmux 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

will no longer work as of tmux 2.4. For the same functionality (using xclip for copying), instead use

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard"
```

from [this blog post](https://shapeshed.com/custom-vim-bindings-in-tmux-2-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that may affect this: tmux turns on vi keys for copy mode only if it finds '*vi*' in $VISUAL or $EDITOR. I had changed both to use neovim remote tool (nvr -ls) and suddenly tmux copy keys I had bound in copy-mode-vi stopped working because it defaulted back to using emacs keybindings. Check that your $VISUAL and EDITOR contains some version of the string 'vi'.